# How can we use HDD space as RAM in oracle virtualbox

Tags: memory-management, virtualbox

Machine specification : 5 GB RAM and 2 TB HDD. On this machine, I have installed Oracle virtual box and now I have to generate a virtual machine of 16 GB RAM and 500 GB HDD. But these both should be generated using HDD space. Can anyone guide me on how I can use HDD space as RAM in virtual machine. This is regarding Windows.

Comment: as I now we can use of disk for swapping (virtual memory). On linux you can do this by increasing your swap and in windows by increasing pagefile.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to increase pagefile.

Comment: You have 5GB of RAM and want to give 16GB of them to a virtual machine? How is your host going to continue to run with -11GB of RAM?

Comment: in windows run type sysdm.cpl this open system properties wizard. in advanced tab /performance section click on settings again in advanced tab in new wizard in virtual memory section you can change it. of course this can a little difference in windows versions